# How to give admin ability to change media path using frontend in django?

Tags: django

I want to give admin ability to change media path in django whatever he want in server system. can anybody tell me how can i do this?

below is code in Settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = location('public/media')
```

I want to change Media_Root directory . But only admin can change media directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope If this Works

```
def custom_upload_function(obj, f_name):
    "here u may get path from admin or from some where stored in to database , and replace /media/ with admin path"
         return os.path.join('/media/%s/' % obj.id, f_name)

def AbcModel(models.Model):
        profileImage= models.ImageField(upload_to=custom_upload_function, max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```